# Create a MySQL index on already existing table with a lot of data

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, indexing, flyway

I have a Spring Boot service with a MySQL database (AWS RDS).

There is a specific table, that contains around 2 millions of rows, and some queries on it make the CPU go up to the database instance.

I noticed that there isn't an index on the used column so I would like to try to add this index.

The questions are:

- Can I add (without any problems) this index on this table that
  already contains a lot of rows? I'm using Flyway to manage the db
  migrations.
- The specific column contains strings, are there some
  other index configurations that It's better to use for this scenario?

Some additional infos:

- MySQL version is `5.7.33`;
- The table, at the moment, does not contain any other relationships;
- The table is very simple and it's reported below:

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `info`(

  `field_1` varchar(36) NOT NULL,

  `field_2` text DEFAULT NULL,

  `my_key` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,

  `field_3` varchar( 255) DEFAULT NULL,

  `field_4` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,

  `field_4` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,

  `field_6` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,

  `field_7` varchar(36)NOT NULL,

  `creation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,

  `modification_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`field_1`)

  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
- The table contains now around **2 millions** of rows;
- The query is something like:

  SELECT * FROM info WHERE my_key = "xxxx"

  and it will be executed a lot of times

The idea is to create this index:

```
CREATE INDEX my_key ON info (my_key);
```

Comment: Could you post A) your query and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; and C) SHOW INDEX FROM tbl_name; for analysis and D) name of the column you want to index ?

Comment: And show us the query.  It may benefit even more from a composite index instead of a single-column index (which is what you are implying).

Comment: How big is the table?  Adding an index is, at worst, proportional to the size of the table.  And what version of MySQL?

Comment: I added the requested info

Comment: The posted SHOW CREATE TABLE xxx; appears to be something made up and not the result of SHOW CREATE TABLE info;    Use of a PRIMARY KEY of VARCHAR(36) will not be efficient long term because every NDX you create will append the content of PRIMARY KEY in the NDX effort.  Consider using ID as an autoincrementing number in the future.  Your use of CREATE INDEX my_key ON info (my_key); would better serve you in the future if you could use something like CREATE INDEX info_ndx_my_key ON info (my_key); to more quickly identify the table as a part of the index name.

Comment: Creating the index on 2 a table with 2 million rows should not be any form strain for your ASW RDS hosted data, just make the index name more significant with the last comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the more recent versions of MySql you can [create an index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html#online-ddl-index-syntax-notes) without locking the table:

> The table remains available for read and write operations while the index is being created. The CREATE INDEX statement only finishes after all transactions that are accessing the table are completed, so that the initial state of the index reflects the most recent contents of the table.

Obviously creating an index is an extra effort for the database so if your database is in suffering state try to update the index when you have a decrease of the activities performed on the db.